# Have sects like Kaulas, Nath, Aghoris and Kamakhya got skull/bone mantras and rituals from the Kapalikas?

Tags: shiva, shaivism, sects, shakti, shaktism

Or did their skull/bone mantras and skull/bone rituals originate on their own?

[image]